# Having trouble determining cause of valgrind error

Tags: valgrind

When I run valgrind on an excerpt of code it tells me my error lies within this line of code but I cannot seem to figure it out (vector_size if of type int):

```
float *rotations = (float *) calloc(vector_size*vector_size, sizeof(float));
```

And here's the valgrind output:

```
Invalid write of size 4
    ==5488==    at 0x109272: main (rotate_vector.c:20)
    ==5488==  Address 0x4a47164 is 0 bytes after a block of size 196 alloc'd
    ==5488==    at 0x4839775: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
    ==5488==    by 0x1091D5: main (rotate_vector.c:8)
    ==5488== 
    ==5488== 
    ==5488== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
    ==5488==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x4E47018
    ==5488==    at 0x109272: main (rotate_vector.c:20)
    ==5488==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
    ==5488==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
    ==5488==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
    ==5488==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
    ==5488==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
```

Any suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: You should post more code. I don't think you have enough information to make any conclusions.

Comment: Valgrind tells you with the first stack trace that you have a problem at line 20 of rotate_vector.c.  It then gives you a second stack trace to give more details about your problem, in this case, the stack trace at which the memory you are overflowing has been allocated.

Answer (score -1):

I usually get those errors when I forget to add 1 to the size you want to alloc.

So it probably comes from your `calloc` size, try adding 1 to it.

You're basically writing past the memory you allocated.

EDIT: Valgrind is telling you that you're trying to write 4 bytes (the size of a float) outside (and after) the memory you allocated. So you need to allocate 4 more bytes to store that last float value.

Comment: I would say that : ```float *rotations = (float *) calloc((vector_size*vector_size) + 1, sizeof(float));```.